# Error at runtime, sbt compilation passes

Tags: scala, sbt, spark-streaming, sbt-assembly

I have a piece of code that compiles (Scala + Spark 1.6) fine.
I then run it (with Spark 1.6), but it complains about a 1.6 method not being there. What gives ??

**simple.sbt:**

```
name := "Simple Project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repo" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
resolvers += "Conjars" at "http://conjars.org/repo"
resolvers += "cljars" at "https://clojars.org/repo/"

mainClass in Compile := Some("Medtronic.Class")

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "1.6.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "1.7.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch" %% "elasticsearch-spark" % "2.1.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "1.8.0"
```

**Compilation:**

```
$ sbt assembly
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/mlieber/projects/spark/test/project
[info] Set current project to Simple Project (in build file:/Users/mlieber/projects/spark/test/)
[info] Updating {file:/Users/mlieber/projects/spark/test/}test...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] Scala version was updated by one of library dependencies:
[warn]  * org.scala-lang:scala-library:(2.10.4, 2.10.0) -> 2.10.5
[warn] To force scalaVersion, add the following:
[warn]  ivyScala := ivyScala.value map { _.copy(overrideScalaVersion = true) }
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Here are some of the libraries that were evicted:
[warn]  * org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:1.4.1 -> 1.6.0
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
..

[info] Run completed in 257 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 0
[info] Suites: completed 0, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 0, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] No tests were executed.
..
[info] Including from cache: spark-core_2.10-1.6.0.jar
..
[info] Including from cache: spark-streaming_2.10-1.6.0.jar
..
[info] Assembly up to date: /Users/mlieber/projects/spark/test/target/scala-2.10/stream_test_1.0.jar
[success] Total time: 98 s, completed Jan 28, 2016 4:05:22 PM
```

**I run with:**

```
./app/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-submit --jars /Users/mlieber/app/elasticsearch-1.7.2/lib/elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar  --master local[4] --class "MyClass"    ./target/scala-2.10/stream_test_1.0.jar
```

**Compilation error:**

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.PairDStreamFunctions.mapWithState(Lorg/apache/spark/streaming/StateSpec;Lscala/reflect/ClassTag;Lscala/reflect/ClassTag;)Lorg/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/MapWithStateDStream;    
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:665)
..
    16/01/28 18:35:23 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

Comment: If you use `%%` do not use `_2.10` - spark-streaming, write `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.6.0"`

Answer (score 2):

Your project is suffering from [Dependency Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell). What is happening is that SBT resolves the transitive dependencies by default and one of your dependencies (`elasticsearch-spark`) requires another version of `spark-core`. From your logs:

```
[warn] Here are some of the libraries that were evicted:
[warn]  * org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:1.4.1 -> 1.6.0
```

Looks like the version required by `elasticsearch-spark` is not binary compatible with the one being used by your project, then you get an error when your project runs.

There is no error at compile time because the code being compiled (aka your code) is compatible with the version resolved.

Here are some options about how to solve this:

1. You can try to upgrade `elasticsearch-spark` to version `2.1.2` and see if it brings a more updated version of `spark-core` (which *could be* compatible with your project). Version `2.2.0-rc1` [depends on `spark-core` 1.6.0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-spark_2.10/2.2.0-rc1) and an upgrade to this version will for sure fix the problem, but keep in mind that you will be using a release candidate version.
2. You can try to downgrade `spark-core` and `spark-streaming` to version `1.4.1` (the one being used by `elasticsearch-spark`) and adapt your code where necessary.

Comment: Thanks! how did you know that the warning/library eviction ("org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:1.4.1 ") really referred to the  elastic search-spark library (which in the .sbt , refers to ""elasticsearch-spark" % "2.1.1"" ) ?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case; i commented out all references to elasticsearch in my code, removed the elasticsearch library references in the .sbt file, and i still get this error. So the error must lie somewhere else ..

Comment: You can use [dependency graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) and see if there is some other dependency adding the incompatible version of spark. Also, check your classpath to see if there is a jar not managed by sbt.